# Is there an way 'We pass $_Get values into an array'

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am getting url string,

> product_cat=booking&min_prep_time=180&max_prep_time=220

and i am passing the values into array with help of **$_GET**. Recently i modified the code in my custom file for  [tax_query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49185/tax-query-parameter-not-working-with-wp-query) and [meta_query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70864/meta-query-compare-operator-explanation), these work fine for me but according to my custom requirement i changed the static values into dynamic variable seems like this

when i used the static value the array is perfectly working and fetched perfect data

> Before Array with static values was working

```
$meta_query[] = array(
                'key'     => '_new_field',
                *'value'   => array(  '19','22'),*
                'compare' => 'between',
                );
```

> After Its not working

```
$meta_query[] = array(
                'key'     => '_new_field',
                *'value'   => array(  $min,$max),*
                'compare' => 'between',
        );
```

This is my complete code i am sure this will help you to understand my problem

```
$prod = isset($_GET['product_cat'])    ? $_GET['product_cat']    : FALSE;
  $min  = isset($_GET['min_prep_time'])  ? $_GET['min_prep_time']  : FALSE;
  $max  = isset($_GET['max_prep_time'])  ? $_GET['max_prep_time']  : FALSE;

      if( $prod && ($prod=="booking") && $min && $max) {

     $tax_query[] = array(

           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',

           'field' => 'slug',

           'terms' => array( $prod ), // Don't display products in the clothing category on the shop page.

           'operator' => 'IN'

    );

        $meta_query = (array)$q->get('meta_query');

        // Add your criteria
        $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'     => '_new_field',
                'value'   => array(  $min,$max),
                'compare' => 'between',
        );    

        // Set the meta query to the complete, altered query
        $q->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
        $q->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
```

### What i want

i just want i passed the values that i get from url and array will perfectly working as it work for static values.
many thanks

Comment: As far as I can see this should work, I recommend var_dumping the values.

Comment: @janw i tried but variable output same , but when i pass same variable to array this cant give me perfect result , in another way if i give static variable then it work for me but static is not the solution